# Firebase unity scoreboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a scoreboard in unity using firebase.
I am trying to retrieve the top 10 scores but am failing horribly.
Here's my format:

[image: Firebase format]

To retrieve this data, I am doing this:

```
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference($"scores/{level}").OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(10)
            .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
```

But, I am getting the data unsorted, and I am not always getting the top 10 scores.

Comment: I answered the "I am not always getting the top 10 scores" is below.  If the "getting the data unsorted" remains after fixing that, please open a new question with the updated data and code, and also show your `HandleValueChanged` implementation there.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the scores as strings, and that means the values are sorted lexicographically. To see where that causes problems, see these values in lexicographical order:

- "1"
- "10"
- "11"
- "2"
- "20"
- "21"
- "3"

This is probably not the order you want these values in, but it is the expected order given that string values are sorted lexicographically.

If you want to get the scores in their proper numerical order, you should store them as numbers.